# Select for loop in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to get the count of benches I have overall. I have multiple schema as classroom and each clsssroom has multiple tables one of them is benches. I want to count number of benches I have in all the schema. So its like classroom A has 6-chairs and 7-benches Classroom B has 2-chairs and 8 benches so I have 15 benches.

I have two queries already

1. `SELECT classroom_name FROM public.classroom`
2. `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM <classroom_name>.benches;`

I want to get all the values from query 1 and loop them in query 2. Solution I came close to is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION all_customers_dynamic() RETURNS SETOF classroom AS $$
DECLARE
  schema RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR schema IN EXECUTE
    format(
      'SELECT classroom_name FROM public.classroom'
    )
  LOOP
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
      format('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM %I.benches;', schema.classroom_name);
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Refer Using dynamic SQL in link https://clarkdave.net/2015/06/aggregate-queries-across-postgresql-schemas/ for more clearnace on my query

Comment: You stated your goal but didn't ask a question or describe what your problem is with the current solution. My guess is that you have a return type mismatch since you defined the function to return `setof classroom` and your return statement returns a `setof bigint`. Unless `classroom` is a table with a single column of a type compatible with `bigint`, this won't work. Replace `RETURNS SETOF classroom` with `RETURNS SETOF bigint`.

Comment: "*I have multiple schema as classroom and each classroom has multiple tables*" - don't do that? Use a single table for the benches and put a classroom column in it.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Data for testing:

```
CREATE SCHEMA classroom1;
CREATE SCHEMA classroom2;

CREATE TABLE classroom1.benches (
    id int4 NULL
);

INSERT INTO classroom1.benches (id) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO classroom1.benches (id) VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO classroom1.benches (id) VALUES(3);
INSERT INTO classroom1.benches (id) VALUES(4);
INSERT INTO classroom1.benches (id) VALUES(5);
INSERT INTO classroom1.benches (id) VALUES(6);

CREATE TABLE classroom2.benches (
    id int4 NULL
);

INSERT INTO classroom2.benches (id) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO classroom2.benches (id) VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO classroom2.benches (id) VALUES(3);
INSERT INTO classroom2.benches (id) VALUES(4);
INSERT INTO classroom2.benches (id) VALUES(5);
INSERT INTO classroom2.benches (id) VALUES(6);
INSERT INTO classroom2.benches (id) VALUES(7);
INSERT INTO classroom2.benches (id) VALUES(8);

CREATE TABLE public.classroom (
    classroom_name varchar NULL
);

INSERT INTO public.classroom (classroom_name) VALUES('classroom1');
INSERT INTO public.classroom (classroom_name) VALUES('classroom2');
```

You have two options for do it.
Get benches tables list from your public.classroom table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION all_customers_dynamic() 
RETURNS int4
AS $$
DECLARE
  sh RECORD;
  k int4;
  total int4;
begin
    total = 0; 

    for sh in execute 
        'SELECT classroom_name FROM public.classroom'
    loop
        execute 'select count(distinct id) from ' || sh.classroom_name || '.benches' into k;
        total = total + k;
    end loop;

    return total; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Get all benches named tables automatically from information_schema (system tables)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION all_customers_dynamic_1() 
RETURNS int4
AS $$
DECLARE
  sh RECORD;
  k int4;
  total int4;
begin
    total = 0; 

    for sh in execute 
        'SELECT schemaname || ''.'' || tablename as tb from pg_catalog.pg_tables where tablename = ''benches'''
    loop
        execute 'select count(distinct id) from ' || sh.tb into k;
        total = total + k;
    end loop;

    return total; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```